# Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-v4

Tags: android, cordova, jitpack, cordova-android

I am trying to build an Android app developed with cordova-android 8.1 and it could not download dependencies, although it worked well less than 2 weeks ago. Have you met this problem? How can this problem be solved?

```bash
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preReleaseBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.support:support-v4:25.+.
  Required by:
      project :app
   > Failed to list versions for com.android.support:support-v4.
      > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+.
  Required by:
      project :app
   > Failed to list versions for com.android.support:appcompat-v7.
      > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

My `build.gradle`:

```bash
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        center()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is the best option or if there is any alternative (or even any side effects), so far I can build the app if I remove these lines from `android/project.properties`

`cordova.system.library.4=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+`
`cordova.system.library.7=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+`
`cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:25.+`
`cordova.system.library.5=com.android.support:support-v4:27.+`
`cordova.system.library.6=com.android.support:support-v4:27.+`
`cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+`

Now my file `project.properties` looks like this:

```bash
target=android-28
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+
cordova.gradle.include.3=phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/app-barcodescanner.gradle
cordova.system.library.8=com.android.support:support-v4:28.+
```

Remark: The build goes further, but I also need to these remove plugins `cordova-plugin-local-notification` and `cordova-plugin-badge` to have a successful build after having removed lines in `android/project.properties`.